# Run php files without Installing Zend optimizer

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, localhost, zend-optimizer

I am trying to run php files on localhost, the php files are encoded with zend, which I am actually not sure why and what purpose does it have. I get the message that to run the files you should download Zend optimizer.

My question is can I run the php files with Installing Zend optimizer, If yes How?, what are the changes I need to make to my php files. Or should I delete some modules inside the scripts directory/

Thanks Mike

Comment: Why don't you simply ask the supplier for the raw source files?

Comment: @PeeHaa: what do you mean by raw source code. I alreday have the source code available in terms of php files and htmls. I think I am just not able to install this properly.

Comment: You said: "the php files are **encoded** with zend"

Comment: @PeeHaa this is the message I am getting when I try to open te site in http://localhost/yoursite/scripts/

The component "Zend Optimizer" is not installed on the Web Server and therefore cannot service encoded files. Please download and install the Zend Optimizer (available without charge) on the Web Server.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few documents in my Knowledge Base about Zend Guard (see links at the bottom) but here's the quick scoop about your question(s).

You cannot run the code without a decoder but the decoders are usually free and installation instructions are provided with the decoder. However, the provider of the php files may have included a license key because they expect you pay a license fee. When you don't have a license key you won't be able to run the encoded files. You cannot make any changes to a file because the integrity of the encoded files is verified at runtime. You don't have to make any changes to your existing php files, unless they are encoded with another provider. You can run encoded and plain php files side by side.

If your php files have been encoded with Zend Guard you will need a decoder from Zend. For PHP up to version 5.2.x you will need "Zend Optimizer" and for 5.3.x "Zend Guard Loader". Both decoders are available for free by Zend and just a single module file you need to have on your server and include the path in your php configuration file (usually php.ini).

Encoding source files is usually done to protect the intellectual property of the code, i.e. nobody can just copy/paste (steal) parts of it. In many cases these applications are also sold and require a license key. In that case somewhere in the php files is the license key hidden and the proper key required to actually run the application. There is maybe also a performance boost because the code is basically pre-compiled.

[Zend Guard/Optimizer](http://www.adrianworlddesign.com/Knowledge-Base/Web-Hosting/Zend-Guard)

Comment: Thats a useful link and good answer Indeed, but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Mike Why, because you don't want to install a decoder on your localhost?

Comment: I do want to  but not sure how to .can you plz send a decoder link and installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
But there are some conditions.
If PHP < 5.3 then you need to zend guard for decode and zend optimizer for encode.
If PHP >= 5.3 then you need to zend guard for decode and zend guard loader for encode.
Only zend optimizer is free and you can download all of them in zend formal website.
There are 2 versions for download.a zip version and a standalone installation version.

Take care

Answer (score -1):

You can only run PHP files w/o Zend Optimizer if you have them in their source form. The source form is the preferred form to make changes to the software.

Contact the person where you obtained those encoded files from and ask for the source form of these files. Then use these instead and you do not need to use the Zend Optimizer.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by source form. I think I have them in source form, like I can open them in notepad and edit.

Comment: And you see **all** the PHP source code? If so, then you won't need Zend Optimizer at all and I wonder a bit why you ask the question. So I'm sure there must be something in between. Where did you obtain those files from?

Comment: I bought a website template with all the source files and htmls plus scripts. I just need to install this.

Comment: should I have zend server to run this. I am running this on wamp now. I think something is wrong the way I have put my files in localhost. May be

Comment: If buying a product has left you in a non-useable state, you should demand for support at the vendor. If the vendor is not able to get the product to work, you should demand the money back.

Comment: I didnt bought the support, I thought it would be easy to install on loclahost. anyways when I also downloaded zend optimiser, but I am not sure where to put this. any clues. I am just looking if  I can  get rid of this msg:
The component "Zend Optimizer" is not installed on the Web Server and therefore cannot service encoded files. Please download and install the Zend Optimizer (available without charge) on the Web Server.

Comment: Sorry, I do not offer support here for proprietary solutions. If you have vendor lock-in, you have vendor-lock-in. That's the way it goes, one of the bad sides of "optimizing" with zend. Better buy [free software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html).